# XSLT trying to add new node and adding element

Tags: xml, xslt

Currently I am trying to convert an word xml to xml file.
And it is trying to do that by identifying styles.

I am currently facing problem here as I am very new to this XLST conversions I am seeking some help.

I am trying to add a new element called `<standingOrder>` in below template an from my word xm looks like

### Word document Text

> 1. PLANNING REGULATIONS (REMOVAL OF PROVISIONS IN RESPECT OF GYPSIES AND TRAVELLERS)
>      **Up to 20 minutes (Standing Order No. 23)** Mr abc That leave be given to bring in a  xxxxxxxxxxxx. Notes: The Member moving and a
>      Member opposing this Motion may each speak for up to 10 minutes.

### Note:

In above text, Up to 20 minutes (Standing Order No.23) (which is highlighted) will have a style called StandingOrderReference and as below xslt code if that finds the text Standing Order No.23 then it should build a child node called `<standingOrder>` and value 23 should be the `innertext` of the node. for that I have done below but I am not able to show the value.

### XSLT

```
<xsl:when test="@styleId='StandingOrderReference'">
   <xsl:element name="standingOrder">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'(Standing Order  ')"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:when>
```

### I am expecting

```
<standingOrder>23</standingOrder>
```

Please correct me where I am doing wrong.
As always any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please show the relevant part of OOXML too (plain text does not help). Otherwise your problem is difficult to diagnose. Perhaps `.` does not mean what you think it does in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment, it would be preferable if you placed the actual xml excerpt in the post. However, making some assumptions, the following xslt:

```
   <xsl:template match="/xml/someElement">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@styleId='StandingOrderReference'">
            <xsl:element name="standingOrder">
               <xsl:value-of select="
                 substring-before(
                   substring-after(.,'(Standing Order No. '), 
                   ')')"/>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

Parses this document:

```
<xml>
   <someElement styleId="StandingOrderReference">
      **Up to 20 minutes (Standing Order No. 23)** Mr a
   </someElement>
</xml>
```

To return what you seem to be after, viz:

```
<standingOrder>23</standingOrder>
```

Note that you'll also need to truncate the substring - I've used a `substring-before` to do this. Note that there is also the word **`No.`** after the `(Standing Order` in the xml.